# Check multiple conditions and perform math with the results

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 1,000 rows.  Each row has six column categories with different weights (30%, 20%, 20%, 10%, 15%, 5%) that are scored either 1,2,3,4,5 or N/A and then a rating which compiles the overall score, so the first row is 5*.3, 2*.2, 1*.1, 1*.15, 5*.05 for a total of 2.4.  I want to reassign the values if a column has N/A so if the first column which is worth 30% has an N/A, I want the new remaining five values to be worth 26%, 26%, 16%, 21%, 11% (yes I would like to add 6% to each and not redistribute the 30% based on current weights).  How do I do this with VBA code?  If two columns have N/A then I will distribute the total weight of those two columns to the other four and so on.  There are 60 combinations and I'm OK with just 60 if - then -else statements.  How I define the fields and ensure the formulas will be dynamic for all 1000 rows?  I am struggling to write the formula / define elements to make it dynamic. Thanks!

```
Option Explicit
Function New_Score()
End Function
Sub TestSum()
   If Range("AD2").Value = "N/A" And Range("AF2").Value = 2 Then
   Range("AJ2").Value = (Range("AF2").Value * 0.3) + (Range("AH2").Value * 0.2)
   End If
   If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "N/A" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 5 Then
   ActiveCell.Value = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value * 0.3) + (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value * 0.2)
   End If
End Sub
```

It's the same attempt twice - first with the range reference and then with the offset reference. It works fine, but not if I drag the cells. How can I reference this dynamically? THANKS!

Comment: What do you mean by dragging the cells? To drag the cells you may want to try the proposal below with cell formula. In VBA you need to loop through the rows and adjust your reference of the cells accordingly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/loop-through-data-using-macro

Comment: BTW, those 60 combinations of IFs can be avoided with the calculation as described in the below answer regardless as cell formula or as VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by braX please share you code and the  problem of it.

The calculation should also be possible to be solved with cell functions with additional supporting columns, e.g.:

- Calculate the sum of percentages of all the NA cells
- Divide it by the number of cells not NA
- Add this value to each of the “base” percentage values
- Multiply with the related factors (With NA=0)

Instead of multiple additional columns you can also put this in one formula in the target column.

edit: this calculation is per row